# Crystal Reports XI - ToWords() function gives random results

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I've got a serious problem with the ToWords function. I'm using Crystal Reports whith Visual Studio 2010 on a french OS. The first time I visualize my report, everything's fine : ToWords function give me a result in french. Next times : ToWords give me a result in english.

I search on forums, I haven't found the solution :(

Thanks in advance.

Fred.

Comment: what have you done next times? and changes done?

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting your question as such, correct anything if necessary:

- Function: ToWords(2)
- Output: 'Deux'
- *Changed nothing, ran it again*
- Output: 'Two'

Questions:
 - Does the report alternate back and forth French/English? Is it random? Is it only in English now? Etc.

Possible Solution:

- File > Options > Formula Editor tab > Default Formula Language dropdown, what are your options here? Can you select French? I'm working on an OS with only one language, not sure what options would be for folks mixing their languages between OS and software.